# I installed Pillow but how do I use it?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am building a python GUI and want to be able to use images. I found several options but Pillow seems like the best option.

I installed Pillow with `pip install Pillow`, however I do not know how to use/import Pillow. I used `import PIL` but I come up with this "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `PIL`. I have tried uninstalling and installing Pillow repeatedly. I tried `pil`, `pillow`, `Pillow`, but I still come up with the same error. I have watched several tutorials, but the latest ones were from 2019. I even noticed that other people were posting comments recently about the same issue.
I picked this bit of code from a guide that is meant to work properly after installing Pillow.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

#Open image using Image module
im = Image.open("images/cuba.jpg")

#Show actual Image
im.show()

#Show rotated Image
im = im.rotate(45)
im.show()
```

Comment: Are you running this code using the same Python installation that you installed Pillow into…!?

Comment: Are you working with a virtual environment? What happens if you open a terminal, start Python there and type "import PIL"? It should work without complaints

Comment: Have tou tryed `pip3 install Pillow`? Maybe you installed it with pip for python2 and you execute your code with python3.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code as my virtual environment. I tried 'pip3 install Pillow' but I still come up with the same issue. No module named 'PIL'. How do I know if I am running Pillow into the same Python installation?

Comment: Which python environment is VS Code configured to use?

Comment: @ Random Davis VS code is currently using Python 3.8.6. 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is an IDE, not a virtual environment. Using both together can be tricky, so I will try to come up with a "fail-safe" way to install Pillow without knowing a lot about your existing configuration.

I suggest you start VSCode and open the file in your question. Mark the line `import PIL` and press SHIFT+ENTER to run it in the built-in terminal in the bottom. The output should be

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
>>>
```

Now, in the terminal, next to the `>>>`, type `quit()` and press ENTER to leave the interpreter. Now, still in the built-in terminal, type `pip3 install pillow`. Run the line `import PIL` again as above, and if it does not work, take a screenshot of the terminal and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. The version that I was running in the program itself (in the terminal) was not the same as the python environment that VS code was currently using(bottom left corner of VS code window).
I made sure that the version used in the terminal was `Python 3.8.6 64-bit` like the one that VSC was using.